# linq like on relational data

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to do a like on a table that has a one to many relationship with another. Having some issues with the code for that. **Promotion** table has a one to many relationship with **PromotionMajorChains**. I am trying to do a like on the PromotionMajorChains table, on the column **MajorChain**. The error I am getting: *CS1503    Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'*

Code:

```
case MAJOR_CHAIN:
         paginatedQueryable = paginatedQueryable.Where(e => EF.Functions.Like(e.Promotion.PromotionMajorChains.Select(mc => mc.MajorChain), $"%{filter.Value}%"));
         break;

Example filter.Value = "group"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a set of records, apply predicates which are dedicated for that

```
paginatedQueryable = paginatedQueryable
   .Where(e => e.Promotion.PromotionMajorChains.Any(mc =>
      EF.Functions.Like(mc.MajorChain, $"%{filter.Value}%")
   );
```